# SSL issue: The private key did not match the public key provided

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl

I followed the instructions outlined [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ssl-server-cert.html) by amazon.

A quick summary:

1. Created a private key
   `openssl genrsa -out my-private-key.pem 2048`
2. Created a CSR`openssl req -sha256 -new -key my-private-key.pem -out csr.pem`

Got a zip from the CA (Comodo in my case) which included

- my-site.crt
- three files representing the certificate chain.

**Question 1:**
Running the following two commands to verify the certificate matches the private key I get different MD5 codes

```
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in my-private-key.pem | openssl md5
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in my-site.crt | openssl md5
```

I.e. the keys do not match. Any idea why?

**Question 2:**
In many places I noticed that documentation asks to convert the key file to a pem file using the following command

```
openssl rsa -in my-private-key.pem -outform PEM > aws.private.pem
```

However the output file is exactly the same as the input. So why do it?

Same for the crt file I got from the CA

```
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in my-site.crt > aws.public.pem
```

Again the output file is exactly the same as the input only with different extension.

Are/Why are these two steps necessary?

Thanks

Comment: This question may be a little to specialist for this forum. You may have better luck on either Information Security or Stack Overflow.

Comment: 1) This is weird, they should match.
2) If the input file and the output format are the same (PEM in your case, another option is DER), I don't see any reason for this. Maybe those guides want to ensure that the file is valid, thus contains only one entry of the desired type.

Comment: @Julian - at the risk of one of those religious debates, Stack Overflow is for programming and development question. I would vote to close this if it landed on SO. I would recommend they visit SU because that's a place to get help with commands, like `openssl rsa` and `openssl rsautl`.

Comment: @nsof - please state where you are getting the error message *"The private key did not match the public key provided"*, and what you did to get into that state.

Comment: @jww - when trying to upload to and Amazon Load Balancer. The problem is not related to them but rather to the fact that the MD5 codes are different. 
I have taken this with the Certificate Authority (Comodo) in my case. Perhaps something related to how I issued the CSR or something on their end.

Comment: @jww - I probably should have said serverfault rather than SO. SU is a site for "computer enthusiasts and power users" so openssl is not off topic which is why I didn't vote to close but the detailed & specific nature of the question means that better help is likely to be available elsewhere.

Comment: @nsof - Ah, OK. I seem to recall something about line endings. Also see the following on Stack Overflow: [“Public key certificate and private key doesn't match” when using Godaddy issued certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6753619). That's an old question, and SO fielded it was because the rules were different back then. The rules are somewhat different now, and we have to move to close them.

Comment: Ad question 1: Have you checked, if both openssl commands return without error? Are both files really PEM encoded? Are the public keys different, if you run `openssl x509` and `openssl rsa` with a `-text` switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question 1

See my comment

### Question 2

The first command (`openssl rsa`) removes the encryption from the keyfile (if there was one). This is neccesary, because webservers usually use an unencrypted keyfile.

The only thing the second command (`openssl x509`) might do is change the PEM header, but it is probably not needed that way. If you used `-inform der` on the command it would convert a binary certificate to a PEM (base64+header) encoded one.

The `-outform PEM` and `-inform PEM` switches of your commands are useless, by the way, as this is the default behaviour of openssl